# ImageIO.read(png) losing its transparency

Tags: java, javax.imageio

I've tested my image when using (1) and it's of type TYPE_3BYTE_BGR while it's a transparent image, when using (2) my image appears with transparency, can someone explain me where I'm doing a mistake please?

Here's my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    Frame frame = new Frame();
    frame.setSize(200, 200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    frame.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.PINK);
    BufferedImage image;
    try{
        image = ImageIO.read(new File("my_path"));
    }catch(IOException e){
        image = null;
    }
    JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("my_path"));
    //JLabel label = new JLabel(new ImageIcon(image));
    frame.getContentPane().add(label);
    label.setBounds(10, 10, 6, 10);
    frame.setVisible(true);

}
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5bDiW.png)'s my image.

Thanks in advance!

PS: Btw site must be broken I was not able to paste my code, had to rewrite it, weird.

PS2: Also it's been the second time my "Hi!" as first line gets removed...

Comment: Someone needs me to clarify something? I really need help on this..

Comment: What does (1) and (2) refer to? Also, it doesn't make any sense that the image has transparency while it has type `TYPE_3BYTE_BGR`, as this type has no transparency... PS: It's generally discouraged to use unnecessary polite phrases, such as "Hi" or "Thanks in advance". Instead, focus on asking a clear question, with the necessary details.

Answer (score 1):

Your image file is a 24 bit RGB PNG file, with an optional `tRNS` chunk, specifying a single RGB color that should be considered transparent (as opposed to a 32 bit RGBA PNG with full alpha channel).

For some reason, the standard `PNGImageReader` that comes with the JRE does *not* create a transparent image for RGB PNGs with a `tRNS` chunk. According the spec, optional chunks (starting with a lowercase letter) can be ignored by a decoder, so this is fully acceptable behavior.

You can, however, read the metadata for the PNG using the ImageIO API, and if there's a `tRNS` chunk, you can create a transparent `BufferedImage` and apply the transparency yourself (replacing all RGB values equal to the RGB value from the `tRNS` chunk). But this is quite some extra work if you just want to read icons bundled with your application.

**The easiest fix would be to just store the PNG with either palette and transparency or a full 32 bit RGBA PNG, which are both supported by ImageIO without any more work.**

The reason why it works using the "direct" `ImageIcon` approach, is that `ImageIcon` uses a completely different PNG decoder than ImageIO, which seemingly does apply the `tRNS` chunk (in your case, but I don't think has to, so the behavior may vary by JRE or platform, you will have to test).